# Abort action execution in BindModel method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have implemented custom model binder in my File Upload Action. Sometimes file upload is dropped by server and BindModel method is called with partial data (ContentLenght and TotalBytes do not match here). I would like to abort Action execution from custom model binder, how to do that?

```
 public class OptionModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var optionModelName = GetOptionModelName(controllerContext);
            if (optionModelName != null) return null// !!!How to abort Action execution?!!! here

                Trace.TraceInformation(optionModelName);
                var model = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(optionModelName);
                bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, model.GetType());

            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

public class OptionModelBinderAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new OptionModelBinder();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> clientUpload, [OptionModelBinder]IOptionViewModel formData)
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to abort Action execution from your model binder ? You can simply notify that your file isn't uploaded correctly : `ModelState.AddModelError(errorMessage, new [] { fileName });` in your model binder, then test `ModelState.IsValid` in your action.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you want to do from the model binding.
The model binding should not control logic behavior. it does not make sense.
I suggest in the controller, you'll ask if something is null and return the appropriate result to the client.
It is not right to let the model binding do the controller's work.